# Removing element(s) of the list of object in objects collection

Tags: c#, linq

For illustration of the problem I created simple example

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<string> Tags {get;set;}
}

List<Product> Products = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product {
                    Id = 1, 
                    Name = "Name1", 
                    Tags = new List<string>{"1254","1234","4355"}
                },
    new Product {
                    Id = 2, 
                    Name = "Name2", 
                    Tags = new List<string>{"1254","1734","2375"}
                },
    new Product {
                    Id = 3, 
                    Name = "Name3", 
                    Tags = new List<string>{"1223","1234","4356"}
                },
    new Product {
                    Id = 4, 
                    Name = "Name4", 
                    Tags = new List<string>{"2345","12344","4357"}
                }
};

List<string> tagsToRemove = new List<string>{"12344", "4355"};
```

So, i want remove from Tags list of every product object all elements that are on tagsToRemove list.
I can do it in foreach loop.

```
        foreach (var tagToRemove in tagsToRemove)
        {
            Products.ForEach(i => i.Tags.Remove(tagToRemove));
        }
```

However I have a feeling that it can be done in simpler way just with linq expression, but how?

Comment: Where does your `ForEach()` come from, this is not Linq, is it?

Comment: ForEach() comes from System.Collections.Generic namespace

Comment: LINQ is not for modifying collections, it is for querying collections. If you are happy with creating a new `List` containing just the `Product`s not on the `tagsToRemove` list, LINQ can do that.

Comment: If you're fine with creating a new reference for the `Tags` property, then `Products.ForEach(x => x.Tags = x.Tags.Except(tagsToRemove).ToList());`

Answer (score 1):

LINQ isn't really for modifying collections. I would code as follows:

First, use `HashSet` for `tagsToRemove` as `Contains` testing is more efficient (probably makes little difference in this case):

```
var tagsToRemove = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "12344", "4355" });
```

Then, use the `RemoveAll` method on the `Tags` list in each `product`:

```
foreach (var product in Products)
    product.Tags.RemoveAll(t => tagsToRemove.Contains(t));
```

Comment: Or `Products.ForEach(product => product.Tags.RemoveAll(t => tagsToRemove.Contains(t)));`

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I don't believe using `ForEach` in that way is an improvement over the regular `foreach` loop - it is slower and I prefer using `ForEach` (and `IEnumerable` extensions of `ForEach`) for actions that don't affect the source.